# Any way to get past Twitter search API 6-9 day limit

Tags: twitter

I have the Twitter search API working in my Rails 3 app. If I tweet with a specific hashtag I can render the tweet in my view just fine. However, I tweeted with the same hashtag a week ago and it isn't included in my search results. I know there is a limitation on the Twitter Search API where only tweets within the last 6-9 days are displayed; however I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to work around that to get tweets from further back?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for dealing with this except for using commercial twitter partners such as datasift which provides a paid service.